# How do I use mock websocket to test for onMessage within a service function?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, websocket, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a service function that opens a websocket, sends, and processes the onMessage for the response. I am using Jasmine to try to create a unit test for this function.

I want to be able to call someService in Jasmine and receive a promise object with a fake response msg. What is the best way for doing this?

```
   callbacks = [];
   self.someService= function(){
            // Generate message
            var msg = "someMsg";

            // Create promise
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            callbacks[id] = deferred;

            // Open Socket
            var ws = $websocket("SomeConnectionPoint");

            // Send request
            ws.send(JSON.stringify(msg));

            // Message Return
            ws.onMessage(function(msg){
                var data = JSON.parse(msg.data);

                if (angular.isDefined(callbacks[id])) {
                    var callback = callbacks[id];
                    delete callbacks[id];
                    callback.resolve(msg);
                    ws.close();
                  } else {
                    console.error("Unhandled message", data);
                  }
            });
            return deferred.promise.then(function(response) {
                return response;
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend you to take a look at angular-websocket tests first https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-websocket/blob/master/test/angular-websocket.spec.js They also use Jasmine to test they own lib.

Then read about $websocketBackend serivce in lib's docs - https://github.com/PatrickJS/angular-websocket You can use it to write unit tests in for your code